# in this C++ transform to vector<string>, how do I write this lambda function to count max words in any sentence?

Tags: c++, algorithm

http://cpp.sh/6qn6jh : Working solution by creating additional vector.

I am looking for a 1 liner solution using C++ STL transform on vector
Find most words in any sentence. Expecting answer as 6.

How do i structure this lambda without creating additional vector as a back_inserter in transform function?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int mostWordsFoundInASentence(vector<string>& sentences) {
        int longest = 0;
       
        transform(sentences.begin(), sentences.end(), sentences.begin(), [](string& line){
            int c = count(line.begin(), line.end(), ' '); // count spaces in each sentence
            longest = c>longest ? c : longest;
        });
        
            
        return longest+1;
    }


int main() {
    vector<string> sentences = {
        {"alice and bob love leetcode"},
        {"i think so too"},
        {"this is great thanks very much"}
    };
    
    cout << mostWordsFoundInASentence(sentences) << endl;
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

> Error: Line 9: Char 13: error: variable 'longest' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified

Comment: Add `longest` to the capture list of the lambda? Also, do you know what `transform` does? Because it seems like you're using it wrong ....

Comment: when i added longest to capture list, it threw an error.
> Line 9: Char 21: error: cannot assign to a variable captured by copy in a non-mutable lambda
            longest = c>longest ? c : longest;
            ~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.

Comment: `[&longest]` is valid ... But even if you get the capture to work properly, your code still won't work. You can't use `transform` the way you are trying to. Well, you could add a `return line;` to it, but that's just terrible code.

Comment: `"Counting spaces    is     not     counting words"`

Comment: for simplicity, lets assume its exactly 1 space between each word. I was mostly looking for a lambda function that i can apply inside transform and do my computation

Comment: Unfortunately, since that web site, that apparently features random coding puzzles, requires a login, neither myself, nor anyone else who doesn't care much about these random coding puzzles, can see what your link says, and can only read what's written in this question. If there's "exactly 1 space", then the shown logic seems correct. If it's not, then you forgot to mention something in your question, and in any case it's unclear why counting spaces requires "creating additional vector". This does not compute, and the question is unclear.

Comment: Updated the link with working solution using lambda capture and back_inserter. I'm looking for a solution without using back_inserter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as a one liner using C++20's ranges library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

int mostWordsFoundInASentence(const std::vector<std::string>& sentences) {
    return std::ranges::max(
        sentences |
        std::ranges::views::transform(
            [](const auto& sentence) -> int {
                return std::count(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), ' ') + 1;
            }
        )
    );
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> sentences = {
        "alice and bob love leetcode",
        "i think so too",
        "this is great thanks very much"
    };

    std::cout << mostWordsFoundInASentence(sentences) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, this works. There's also transform_reduce that i will try